# Apacie 2.4 Randomly Stops Partial Functions

Tags: windows, apache-2.4

I am running Apache 2.4 on Windows 10 and it periodically stops partially functioning.

I have two domains.  Domain1 is a virtual host serving up files from directories.  Domain2 is a series of virtual hosts pointing subdomains to ports on another network server via proxpass.  It all works.

Every few days at random times the proxy subdomains will no longer be accessible and Apache also stops logging all activity to the logs.   Domain1 continues to serve up files successfully.

The only solution I have found is to reboot the computer the server is on.  That fixes it.  I see the same behavior on two different machines so I am thinking its something on my network that is interfering at some point, but I have no idea what.

I have disabled as many services in Windows as I think might cause an issue but so far nothing has fixed it.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved.   A NAS device on the network was adding ports 80 and 443 to the router on it's own duplicating those of the Apache server and confusing it.